# Generate nested HTML code based on the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
[0] => [
  'parent_id' => null,
  'id' => 1,
  'count' => 0
  'children' => [
    [0] => [
      'parent_id' => 1,
      'id' => 11,
      'count' => count11
    ]
    [0] => [
      'parent_id' => 1,
      'id' => 12,
      'count' => count12
    ]
  ]
],
[1] => [
  'parent_id' => null,
  'id' => 2,
  'count' => 0,
  'children' => [
    [0] => [
      'parent_id' => 2,
      'id' => 21,
      'count' => 0,
      'children' => [
        [0] => [
          'parent_id' => 21,
          'id' => 211,
          'count' => count211
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

And I have to create a nested HTML list out of this according to the following pattern:

```
<ul>
<li><span>All categories (count)</span>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Category 1 (count1)</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>Category 11 (count11)</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>Category 12 (count12)</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Category 2 (count2)</span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span>Category 21 (count21)</span>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>Category 211 (count211)</span>
          </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</li>
</ul>
```

The problem is, the count value exists only in leaves, so parents would have to sum all values of their children. Another problem is that I need a header here (all categories), but it doesn't exist in the array.

How can I do this?

I have been trying to come up with some solutions, but none works.

```
public function generateHTML($arr, $html, $depth = 0)
{
  if($depth == 0)
  {
    $html = '<ul><li><span>All categories</span></li>';
  }
  foreach($arr as $key => $value)
  {
    $html .= '<ul><li>';
    $this->generateHTML($arr, $html, $depth++);
    $html .= '</li></ul>';
  }
  if($depth == 0)
  {
    $html = '</ul>';
  }
}
```

I have completely no idea how could this look like.

Comment: can you provide me your array in PHP to do some test ?

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote Here is exactly working code as per your requirement.

```
<?php

class test{

    public function getTree($arr){
        $html = '<ul>';
        foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
            $html .= '<li><span>'.$v['count'].'</span>';

            if(isset($v['children'])){
                if(is_array($v['children'])){
                    $html .= $this->getTree($v['children']);
                }
            }
            $html .= '</li>';
        }
        return $html .= '</ul>';
    }
}


$arr = array(
array(
    'parent_id' => null,
    'id' => 1,
    'count' => 'count1',
    'children' => array(
        array(
            'parent_id' => 1,
            'id' => 11,
            'count' => 'count11'
        ),
        array(
            'parent_id' => 1,
            'id' => 12,
            'count' => 'count12'
        )
    )
),
array(
    'parent_id' => null,
    'id' => 2,
    'count' => 'count2',
    'children' => array(
        array(
            'parent_id' => 1,
            'id' => 21,
            'count' => 'count21',
            'children' => array(
                array(
                    'parent_id' => 21,
                    'id' => 211,
                    'count' => 'count211'
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
);

$obj = new test();
echo $obj->getTree($arr);

?>
```